# Fire OnPropertyChanged on the entire object when one of its fields changes

Tags: wpf, vb.net, inotifypropertychanged

Let's admit a piece of code:

```
    [...]
    Private _filterContacts As FilterContacts
    Public Property FilterContacts() As FilterContacts
        Get
            Return _filterContacts
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As FilterContacts)
            _filterContacts = value
            OnPropertyChanged("FilterContacts")                    
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _branchType As Nullable(Of Integer)
    Public Property BranchType As Nullable(Of Integer)
        Get
            Return _branchType
        End Get

        Set(ByVal value As Nullable(Of Integer))
            _branchType = value
            OnPropertyChanged("BranchType")                
        End Set
    End Property
    [...]

    Public Sub SomeSub()
        FilterContacts.BranchType = BranchType
    End Sub
```

I actually change the filter's "branchType", but I want to be notified that FilterContacts has changed, not just one of its fields. Is it possible? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Set(ByVal value As Nullable(Of Integer))
    _branchType = value
    OnPropertyChanged("BranchType")                
    OnPropertyChanged("FilterContacts")      
End Set
```

Or, if you want to invalidate all properties on the object, simply do this:

```
OnPropertyChanged("")
```